# Is it possible to open a specific app page by mail link?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I'm developing an hybrid application by using Angular and Ionic and I need to setup a "reset password" flow: once the user clicks on a "reset password" button they receive a mail link to reset.

If the mail link is clicked and the user has the app installed I'd like to open the app and show a password creation page.
Is this possible? Does it work on both ios and android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.
You can use deep linking.

Comment: And it's also possible to have a fallback in the case the link is opened on a desktop mail client? I image this would only work if I open the link on my phone's mail client

Comment: No deep linking main work is where it is declared. If it is declared in ur ionic app , then if your app is installed on device and the link is pressed from whatever place(website/email app/gmail app) then it will open the app. Else if the app wasn't installed,then the link will go to its normal path and from pc the same (will go to its normal path except if you declare a deep linking from the site the link was pressed).